# Not able to change value of Global var from inside function

Tags: javascript, velo

I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819440/update-global-variable-from-a-function-in-the-javascript) but it didn't work for me. In my case I am trying to save a variable using 1 function and call it from another

```
var postalcode = "code didn't change";

export function save_postal_code(code) {
        var localcode = code
        let postalcode = localcode;
        console.log(code);
}

export function get_postal_code() {
        console.log(postalcode);
        return postalcode;
}
```

The save_postal_code function logs the correct value, but the get_postal_code function doesn't. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting. you are declaring a new variable "postalcode" that is local, so it is not going to have anything to do with the global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redeclaring `postalcode` inside `save_postal_code()` instead of updating its value.
The code needs further revision, but that's outside the scope of this answer.
To have `postalcode` updated inside `save_postal_code()`, try:

```js
var postalcode = "code didn't change";

function save_postal_code(code) {
    let localcode = code
    postalcode = localcode;
}

function get_postal_code() {
    return postalcode;
}

save_postal_code("123")
console.log(get_postal_code())
```

Comment: Your snippet in StackOverflow works, but it is not working for my website. I am using Wix Velo to make my website, maybe there is an issue with Wix?

Comment: Wix may be limiting your JavaScript execution, but It's very difficult to know exactly what's going on with your code remotely.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're instantiating the variable again using the `let` keyword (making a more immediate local variable with the same name)

removing the let keyword should fix your issue

```
var postalcode = "code didn't change";

export function save_postal_code(code) {
        var localcode = code
        postalcode = localcode;
        console.log(code);
}

export function get_postal_code() {
        console.log(postalcode);
        return postalcode;
}
```

Comment: If you would explain why this works (he's declaring a new local variable with the same name that shadows the global) it would significantly improve this answer.  A reference to how JS treats variables would be even better :)